# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with memset

Tags: c++, xcode

Getting error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

```
unsigned char *nkey;

memset(nkey, 0x00, 256); // error is here
```

I am setting `nkey` with a `sprintf` then after I use it as a parameter.

There are no compile time errors, but when running it shows that. I am using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to allocate memory for `nkey`, for example

```
unsigned char *nkey = new unsigned char[256]; // block of 256 uchars
```